# Are there any code libraries or languages with built-in support for Metric Time?

Tags: standards

[Metric time is documented here.](http://zapatopi.net/metrictime/)

I'm looking for any implementations of Metric time to Anglo-Babylonian Time (see article link) either as a library or built-into a programming language.

With all the "joke" programming languages out there, it's possible that someone has done this.

P.S. I realize that it is trivial. This question is for FUN.

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you're interested in using Metric time in your app. ;)

Comment: I was looking for an odd little easter-egg to add to one of my apps. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you mentioned has a UMT clock on it, and the [source is in JavaScript](http://zapatopi.net/metrictime/clock.js). This script seems like a good place to start, it is pretty short and easy to read.  Translating it to another language would be cake.  I somehow doubt that there are too many libraries, and almost certainly no languages with it built in.

Comment: Hey. Good catch. I totally didn't notice that.